# dictionary value in a python project

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am stuck on one part of my project. In this project, we must read a library file into a dictionary to create something like:

```
inventory = {author: "book title, quantity, price"}
```

which I have already done. We must then make a function for

1. display library, sorted.
2. add a book to an author.
3. change a quantity of a book.
4. calculate the total money in the library.
5. quit.

I am stuck on part 3, here is what I have so far, but I do not know how to check if the book title is in the inventory because each word in the title is capitalized.

```
    def changeQty(inventory):
        author = inventory.keys()
        book = inventory.values()
        lastName = raw_input("Enter the author's last name: ").capitalize()
        firstName = raw_input("Enter the author's first name: ").capitalize()
        check = lastName + ", " + firstName
        while check not in author:
            print "There is no author by that name in the library."    
            lastName = raw_input("Enter the author's last name: ").capitalize()
            firstName = raw_input("Enter the author's first name: ").capitalize()
            check = lastName + ", " + firstName

        #after here i am stuck trying to make the title of 1 OR MORE words all                   
        #capitalized, to check to see if the title is in reference.getTitle()
        #example: title of dickens, charles would be Hart Times
        title = raw_input("Enter the title: ")
        for info in book:
            for reference in info:
                while title not in reference.getTitle():
                    print "This book does not exist in the library."
                    title = raw_input("Enter the title: ")
    def main():
        inventory = {}
        test = readDatabase(inventory)
        done = False
        while not done:
            menuOpt = raw_input("Please choose a menu option: ")
            if menuOpt == '3':
                newQty = changeQty(inventory)
            elif menuOpt == '5':
                print "Thank you for choosing this program to view your inventory"
                print "Now exiting"
                done = True
            else:
                print str(menuOpt) + " is outside this program's options."
                print "Please choose again."
    main()

    class Book:
        #constructor
        def __init__(self, title, qty, price):
            self.title = str(title)
            self.qty = int(qty)
            self.price = float(price)

        #Accessors:
        def getTitle(self):
            return self.title

        def getQte(self):
            return self.qty

        def getPrice(self):
            return self.price

        def getTotal(self):
            return self.price * self.qty

        #Mutators:
        def setQty(self, newQty):
            self.qty = newQty

        def setPrice(self, newPrice):
            self.price = newPrice

        #Display method
        def displayInfo(self):
            print "\tTitle: " + self.title
            print "\tQty: " + str(self.qty)
            print "\tPrice: %.2f", %self.price
```

I omitted some complete functions, but for the sake of argument, assume that in `def changeQty(inventory)`, book is a list of objects: title, quantity, price.

Comment: can you give an example of one of your entry?

Comment: say inventoy = {"Dickens, Charles": "Hard Times", 8, 8.99}

Comment: check the code below, if I understood your problem correctly

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work:

```
if title.lower() !=reference.getTitle().lower():

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title.lower() #or you can call this method when you want to do the comparison
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Also, the books title should be able to be entered in any way, such as title = "hArD TiMes" but it should end up looking like title = "Hard Times" to check if the book is in the inventory

Comment: well when you use `str.lower()` it convert all the letter to lower case like :  "hArD TiMes".lower() becomes 'hard times'. you can (and I guess you should) class this method on both user input title and inventory title and then check if they are equal .

Comment: This does not seem to work either, though I do not see anything wrong with the code

Comment: When I put in a print statement, it seems that the title from inventory only looks at the first book by the author

Comment: that means now the problem is somewhere else, not the title comparison. Actually I am a bit confused about the `book` variable ? can you tell me what is that exactly ? what does it mean it a list of object like [title,quantity ,price]? if it's the case why do you loop through all element of that instead of just looking at title part?

Comment: what if you change the code to if title.lower()!= reference.getTitle().lower():

Comment: book is the value part of the dictionary. in my Book class (posted after main) i have a constructor for a book as (title, qty, price), which is what book is. It is supposed to be a constructed list of objects of [title, price, qty] where the list is added to the value "author" so that each author can have many books, with different object values. I loop through all the elements because i want to just grab the title element, and a list has no function .getTitle(), so i need to do (element in list).getTitle()

Comment: but you use `info[0]` and get read of the second for loop as you already know the first element is title. did you use the updated code ? I guess  it also would be good idea to put a print after second for loop and print out reference

Answer (score 0):

You may be dealing with extra white space, in which case .trim() can help, but overall for string comparison, I find .contains()  more useful than  ==.

Like Moj's example above, but:

```
if title.lower().contains(reference.getTitle().lower().trim()):
    #do stuff
```